# Can't flash Unofficial CM 12.1 on GS3

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3

After figuring out how to flash the official Cyanogenmod 11 to my GS3 I thought it was time to pick up a new project, the unofficial 12.

So for some reason I can't flash the unofficial Cyanogenmod 12.1 on my Galaxy S3.

I'm following [these](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/development/rom-temasek-s-unofficial-cyanogenmod-12-t3086689) install instructions, along with the ones from the [CM website](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_d2lte) because I'm still a bit new.

I flashed the TWRP recovery just fine, I've never used it before, and then pushed the zip to the phone and tried to install. But I get this error:

```
Updating partition details...
...done
Full SELinux support is present.
Running boot script...

Finished running boot script.
MTP Enabled
Installing '/sdcard/cm-12.1-20150516-UNOFFICIAL-temasek-i9300-V11.5.zip'...
Checking for MD5 file...
Skipping MD5 check: no MD5 file found
This package is for device: m0, i9300, GT-I9300; this device is d2tmo.
E: Error executing updater binary in zip '/sdcard/cm-12.1-20150516-UNOFFICIAL-temasek-i9300-V11.5.zip'
Error flashing zip '/sdcard/cm-12.1-20150516-UNOFFICIAL-temasek-i9300-V11.5.zip'
Updating partition details...
...done
```

Now I realize that it tells me the issue is that the build is made for i9300 and not d2tmo.
I have the T-Mobile one. Is there a version for this phone? 
Or have a just made a huge mistake and misunderstood what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *never* try and flash software from a different device, or a different model of the same device. You could end up bricking your phone.

Regardless, `d2mo` has official CyanogenMod support. You can use the [CyanogenMod installer](http://get.cm) or download a flashable zip from [here](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=d2tmo).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that I was using the wrong one. I also didn't realize that Cyanogenmod had an official version.